# Using session variables to distinguish between type of website users example Admin or Member

Tags: php, mysql, session

HI I'm trying to distinguish if a user using my website is an admin or a member. I have a database where I have table for user roles for example userRole 1 = member and userRole2 = admin. I have this code that gets the userRoleID for that that specific user and stores it in a variable:

```
$result = "SELECT userRoleID FROM tbl_users" or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));

                $res = $con->query($result);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
                    $UserRoleID = $row['userRoleID'];

                    $_SESSION['user_role'] = $UserRoleID;
                }
```

It is working successfully.

As you can see in the last line of the code I'm trying to store the variable that contains the userID in a session variable that was successful too.

Now I'm trying to use that session variable in another php page to decide what to show to the user i.e if he is an admin he gets more features and if he is a member he gets less. I have this code:

```
<?php

        if (!empty($_SESSION['user_role'] == '2')) 
        { ?>
        <li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href='loginpage.php'>Login</a></li>

        <?php } else if ($_SESSION['user_role'] == '3') 
        { ?>
        <li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href='loginpage.php'>Login</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Admin</a></li>


        <?php } ?>
```

As you can see if in this code it decides what menu items it show to the user according to his user role. But it's not working I'm getting these errors:

Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\WSSA1S1\new\pagetemplateHEADER.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\WSSA1S1\new\pagetemplateHEADER.php on line 14

I think the reason for this is because there are no session_start() in the beginning of the php code but when I insert session_start() I get this error:

Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\WSSA1S1\new\pagetemplateLOGINSEC.php on line 4

Can someone give me some suggestions?

P.S I am a beginner for PHP, MySql and stackoverflow so please take it easy on me if the solution was easy.

Comment: `(!empty($_SESSION['user_role'] == '2')` is not a good idea. Please try `if( isset($_SESSION['user_role']) && ($_SESSION['user_role'] == '2') )` this will avoid the `Undefined variable` Notices

Comment: This is because you didn't `session_start()` at the top

Comment: please read carefully @Scorpion

Comment: `$result = "SELECT userRoleID FROM tbl_users" or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));`....says it all..... wouldn't you throw in a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @steven that removed my errors thanks but now the HTML code that is between the php tags is still not showing up.

Comment: so think about the Comment of Darren. 2 Possible reasons: 1. the `$_SESSION['user_role']` is not set, 2. The value of `$_SESSION['user_role']` in not 2 or 3

Comment: That did not change anything @Darren

Comment: @user3136576 do you mind `var_dump($res)` and `var_dump($row)`

Answer (score 0):

```
to keep things simple,
I would suggest something like the following:

<?php

    if( (isset($_SESSION['user_role']) ) && (false != $_SESSION['user_role']) )
    {
        if( '2' == $_SESSION['user_role'] ) 
        { 
            echo "<li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>";
            echo "<li><a href='#'>About Us</a></li>";
            echo "<li><a href='#'>Contact Us</a></li>";
            echo "<li><a href='loginpage.php'>Login</a></li>";
        } 

        elseif ('3' == $_SESSION['user_role'] ) 
        { 
            echo "<li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>";
            echo "<li><a href='#'>About Us</a></li>";
            echo "<li><a href='#'>Contact Us</a></li>";
            echo "<li><a href='loginpage.php'>Login</a></li>";
            echo "<li><a href='#'>Admin</a></li>";
        } 

        else
        { // error condition
            // display details of invalid $_SESSION['user_role']
        }
    }

    else
    { // error condition
        // display details of missing or empty $_SESSION['user_role']
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer @user3629249 but the html tags are still not being outputted for some reason :/